# I'm new to AngularJS and I'm just trying to route to a particular page(html link) after logging via facebook

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my front page where I have two login buttons - 'indexnew.html'

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Webslesson Tutorial | File Upload Using AngularJS with PHP script</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script> 
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <!-- Include Bootstrap CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Student/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <!-- Include main CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Student/css/style.css">
   <!-- Include jQuery library -->
   <script src="Student/js/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Include AngularJS library -->
   <script src="Student/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Include Bootstrap Javascript -->
   <script src="Student/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      </head>  
      <body>  
      <script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1906825872905514',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.10'

    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div
  class="fb-like"
  data-share="true"
  data-width="450"
  data-show-faces="true">
</div>
            <br />  
<div id="fb-root"></div>
             
           <div class="container wrapper"  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


  <hr>
   <div class="row" id="homepage">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
     <h2>STUDENT DETAILS DATABASE</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-top: 10px;">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg pull-right" ng-show="show_form" ng-click="formToggle2()">REGISTER</button>
       </div>

       <div class="col-sm-2"  style="padding-top: 10px; padding-right: 30px;">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg pull-right" ng-show="show_form" ng-click="formToggle1()"> LOGIN </button>
         </div>
                  
   <div style="padding-top: 10px;" class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
    

                     
       
      </div>
     <hr>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
     <div ng-include src="'Forms/userlogin.html'"></div> 
     <div ng-include src="'Forms/userreg.html'"></div>
     <div ng-include src="'Forms/success.html'"></div>
     <div ng-include src="'Forms/invalid.html'"></div>
     <div ng-include src="'Forms/error.html'"></div> 
     <div ng-include src="'Forms/login.html'"></div> 
    </div>
           </div>
           <script src="js1/angular-script.js"></script>   
           <script>
                watchLoginChange = function() {

  var _self = this;

  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(res) {

    if (res.status === 'connected') {

      /*
       The user is already logged,
       is possible retrieve his personal info
      */
      _self.getUserInfo();

      /*
       This is also the point where you should create a
       session for the current user.
       For this purpose you can use the data inside the
       res.authResponse object.
      */

    }
    else {

      /*
       The user is not logged to the app, or into Facebook:
       destroy the session on the server.
      */

    }

  });

}

getUserInfo = function() {

  var _self = this;

  FB.api('/AngularJS/Student/index.html', function(res) {
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      $rootScope.user = _self.user = res;
      
    });
  });

}

logout = function() {

  var _self = this;

  FB.logout(function(response) {
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
      $rootScope.user = _self.user = {};
    });
  });

}
           </script>
      </body>  
      </html>
```

This is the angularjs script page - 'angular-script'

```js
// Application module
var app = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);



app.run(['$rootScope', '$window', 'srvAuth',
  function($rootScope, $window, sAuth) {

  $rootScope.user = {};

  $window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // Executed when the SDK is loaded

    FB.init({

     

      appId: '***************',


      channelUrl: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization#plugins',

      
      status: true,

     

      cookie: true,

     

      xfbml: true
    });

    sAuth.watchAuthenticationStatusChange();

  };

  (function(d){
   
    var js,
    id = 'facebook-jssdk',
    ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
      return;
    }

    js = d.createElement('script');
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";

    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);

  }(document));

}]);

app.controller("myCtrl",['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){


// Enabling show_form variable to enable Add employee button
$scope.show_form = true;
// Function to add toggle behaviour to form
$scope.formToggle1 =function(){
$('#logForm').slideToggle();
$('#regForm').css('display', 'none');
$('#success').css('display', 'none');
$('#invalid').css('display', 'none');
$('#error').css('display', 'none');
$('#login').css('display', 'none');
}

$scope.formToggle2 =function(){
$('#regForm').slideToggle();
$('#logForm').css('display', 'none');
$('#success').css('display', 'none');
$('#invalid').css('display', 'none');
$('#error').css('display', 'none');
$('#login').css('display', 'none');
}

$scope.regInfo = function(info)
{
 $http.post('User/register.php', {"user":info.user,"pass":info.pass} ).success(function(data)
 { 
  if(data==true){   
   
   $('#success').css('display', 'block');
   $('#regForm').slideUp(); 
   $('#logForm').css('display', 'none');
   $('#invalid').css('display', 'none');
   $('#error').css('display', 'none');
   $('#login').css('display', 'none');
  }
  else
  {   
   $('#error').css('display', 'block');
   $('#regForm').slideUp(); 
   $('#logForm').css('display', 'none');
   $('#invalid').css('display', 'none');
   $('#success').css('display', 'none');
   $('#login').css('display', 'none');   
  }
 });
}
 

$scope.loginInfo = function(info)
{
 $http.post('User/login.php', {"user":info.user,"pass":info.pass} ).success(function(data)
 { 
  if(data==true)
  {   
   $('#login').slideToggle(); 
   $('#invalid').css('display', 'none');
   $('#logForm').css('display', 'none');
   $('#success').css('display', 'none');
   $('#regForm').css('display', 'none');
   $('#error').css('display', 'none');
   $('#homepage').css('display', 'none'); 
  }
  else
  {
   $('#invalid').css('display', 'block');
   $('#logForm').slideUp();
   $('#success').css('display', 'none');
   $('#regForm').css('display', 'none');
   $('#error').css('display', 'none');
   $('#login').css('display', 'none');
  }
 });
}

$scope.logout = function()
{
 $('#homepage').css('display', 'block');
 $('#login').css('display', 'none');
   
}



}]);
```

This is the html page I want to display when a person logins from facebook (the other button is working but not the facebook-login button) - 'index.html'

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>AngularJS CRUD Operations Demo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- Include Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Include main CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<!-- Include jQuery library -->
<script src="js/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include AngularJS library -->
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include Bootstrap Javascript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container wrapper" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<!--<h1 class="text-center">AngularJS CRUD Operations Demo</h1>-->

<hr>

   <div class="row" id="homepage">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
     <h2>STUDENT DETAILS OF CLASS X</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="padding-top: 10px;">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg pull-right" ng-show="show_form" ng-click="formToggle()">ADD NEW STUDENT</button>
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-2"  style="padding-top: 10px;">
       <p><a ngsubmit="$facebook.logout()" href="/Angularjs/facebookLogin/indexnew"> LOGOUT </a></p>
         </div>
                     
       
      </div>

      
     <hr>
     <div class="alert alert-default input-group search-box">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Student Details Into Database..." ng-model="search_query">
   </span>
  </div>

     <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

   <!-- Include form template which is used to insert data into database -->
   <div ng-include src="'templates/exist.html'"></div> 
   <div ng-include src="'templates/form.html'"></div>
   <!-- Include form template which is used to edit and update data into database -->
   <div ng-include src="'templates/editForm.html'"></div>
  </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
      <br /><br />
<!-- Table to show employee detalis -->
<div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
     
     <th>Name of Student</th>
     <th>Father's Name</th>
     <th>Email Address</th>
     <th>Gender</th>
     <th>Edit</th>
     <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="detail in details| filter:search_query">
     
     <td>{{detail.std_name}}</td>
     <td>{{detail.std_father}}</td>
     <td>{{detail.std_email}}</td>
     <td>{{detail.std_gender}}</td>
     <td>
      <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="editInfo(detail)" title="Edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
     </td>
     <td>
      <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="deleteInfo(detail)"
      ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
    </div>
   </div>
   <script src="js/angular-script.js"></script>
   
       
  </body>
</html>
```

Kindly help me to logout from facebook when I click the logout button too.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please remove all redundant code that not relevant to your issue

Comment: And remove all of the empty whitespace.  Way too much scrolling required.